# Does mongodb's eval() lock the database or not?

Tags: mongodb, eval

According to the documentation:

```
By default, eval takes a global write lock before evaluating the
JavaScript function.
```

But you can pass an option to disable this write lock:

```
Set nolock to true on the eval command to prevent the eval command
from taking the global write lock before evaluating the JavaScript.
```

But then I see this warning:

```
Do not use eval for long running operations as eval blocks all
other operations. Consider using other server side code execution options.
```

So, what is it? Does eval() halt every other operation from running or not?

And if it does: why would you be able to disable the "global write lock", as nothing else can run anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `eval()` takes the global write lock, blocking all other operations.  If however you provide the `nolock` it will not take the write lock, so it won't block all other operations.  However, even with `nolock` provided, the global write lock may be taken by the code within the eval block.

Overall, it is not recommended to use `eval()`, it doesn't work with sharding, and in recent versions of the server it can only be run by admins.